# reporting (small) achievements, then loading them returns none

Tags: ios8, game-center, achievements

I am reporting several [GKAchievement](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKAchievement_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/GKAchievement/reportAchievements:withCompletionHandler:)s with `reportAchievements:withCompletionHandler:` to Game Server and receive no errors.

However, when I request them immediately afterwards with `loadAchievementsWithCompletionHandler:` I receive an empty array of achievements (and again no error) instead of the expected ones.

This is happening in the sandbox environment. The reported achievements have small `percentComplete` (above 0%, but below 1%, i.e. far below 100%), but I should still be able to load them, right?

Am I doing something wrong here? Has anybody observed similar behavior?

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that percentages under 1 don't work in the sandbox. The documentation mentions nothing about this limitation:

> The range of legal values is between 0.0 and 100.0, inclusive.

This makes me think that it's just a sandbox thing to save traffic. Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem apparently goes away if `percentComplete >= 1`. I've just tried with 2% and that worked.